# Pull times from a database and send out messages at that particular time

Tags: java, delay, sendmessage, tibco, kdb

I have a q/kdb database where one of the columns has times. I want to take the data in each row, and send it out with tibco rendezvous at the time specified in the time column of each row.
What would be the best way to do this?

It seems possible using the java timer and delay classes, or maybe with some third party stuff.
Note: the complex part here is that I'm not sending out at a regular interval, i need to go to database to determine the time at which each message is sent.

So for example if the first two values in the column are 14:00:00.000 14:30:00.000 then the first message will be sent out at 2pm and the second will be sent out at 2:30pm.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take look at `ScheduledExecutorService`, it has a `schedule(Runnable command, long delay, TimeUnit unit)` method that might do what you want

Comment: this seems like a pretty good option. although ideally what i'm looking for is to have something execute at a particular time. So for example if the database says 2pm i would want it to execute at 2pm. As is in this method, I would have to set a delay, which might not end up being very accurate.

Comment: It will give you nano-second precision, so unless you want the event to occur exactly @ 02:00:00.00 you should be able to calculate a delay within a reasonable error margin.  Alternatively, you could google for a crone job implementation such as http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/cron4j/ ... I found a number listed.

Comment: I've used ScheduledExecutorService in the past to great success, schedule jobs as close to five minutes up to days in the future, but that's just me

Comment: hmmm  i suppose. i guess i wasn't quite understanding how to use this. i think at this point i'll try to find the current time using calendar and maybe compare it to the time in the database to determine the delay. I can't compare milliseconds to epoch though because i'll have times that occured on an older date.

Comment: also for scheduledexecutorservice it says one of the parameters is a runnable. i'm not quite sure what this means. I guess i'm not just putting in a method i want to execute, but i need to make a new thread? do you have any advice on how to satisfy the first parameter of the scheduledexecutorservice? thanks!

Comment: Runnable is a interface with a single method called "run". Typically ths is passed to a thread which executes run in your behalf.  The executor service is a type of thread pool, it takes care of this for you

Comment: As for calculating the delay, you could create two calendars, one for the current time & one for the execution time, if the execution time is less (before) the current time, the you need to add a day to it

Comment: sorry didn't realize i could do that!